# WooCommerce Template overriding not working with woocommerce.php

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, template-hierarchy

I am creating a custom theme with my own HTML. I am trying to override woocommerce template. I have created a template named with `woocommerce.php` but it still shows template with default structure.

I checked the system status and it says that `Your theme has a woocommerce.php file, you will not be able to override the woocommerce/archive-product.php custom template since woocommerce.php has priority over archive-product.php. This is intended to prevent display issues.`

But when I load the `shop page` it opens up with default structure.

Some screenshots

1. [Folder Structure](https://prnt.sc/ljfqge)
2. [WooCommerece system status](https://prnt.sc/ljfqzi)
3. [woocommerece.php](https://prnt.sc/ljfrn5)

Comment: chnage folder name woocommerce2 to woocommerce

Comment: copy this file to /themes/themexxxx/woocommerce folder:

Comment: I want to override from woocommerce.php instead of customizing whole template.

Comment: i think this not possible because this is main plugin file of woocommerce.

Comment: please see this link : https://theme.co/apex/forum/t/archive-product-php-override-woocommerce-php/39037

Comment: I think you are understanding just opposite. I want to use woocommerce.php template not the default structure.

Comment: means please clear ?

Comment: I want to override default structure by creating a woocommerce.php file

Comment: Code in woocommerce.php doesn't matter. Just say I am printing anything on it. Problem is woocommerce/WordPress does not select this template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix that by disabling Woocommerce template debug mode in config.php.

```
define( 'WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE', false );
```

You can check if the template debug mode is set via:

WP Dashboard -> WooCommerce -> System Status -> Tools

Answer (score 8):

It's a custom theme, so first of all you should check if WooCommerce support is declared in the `functions.php`.

WooCommerce can be integrated with the theme by using `woocommerce_content()` (`woocommerce.php` file) or by template overrides, but in both cases the declaration of support in the theme is required.

```
function wpse319485_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse319485_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.